# Python : include file from parents sub folder

Tags: python, include

I have a script i need to call but it does not work.

here's my structure:

```
/webpy/lib/debug.py
/webpy/htdocs/__init__.py
```

in my /webpy/htdocs/**init**.py i try to call:

```
from ..lib.debug import logme
```

but i get:

attempted relative import beyond top-level package

how can i fix this?

Comment: try to add the file `/webpy/__init__.py` and make `webpy` your top-level package if that does not mess with your package logic...

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../..")
from lib.debug import logme
```

Comment: i'd advise against messing with your PYTHONPATH inside a package. only the 'main' script may modify the PYTHONPATH (if necessary); the packages should not. (in my opinion, that is.)